# Approximation of the solution of an IVP

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem 
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = x^2 + y^2, \\
y(0) = 0$$

on D = {|x| <= 1, |y| <= 1}

Find the third approximation to the solution

If someone could maybe walk me through the steps that would be most appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take, as suggested, $D:|x|,|y|\le 1$, where $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2\le 2=M.$ Then according to Picard-Lindelof your IVP enjoys existence and uniqueness when
$$
\lvert x\rvert\le\min\left\{a,b/M\right\}=\min\left\{1,1/2\right\}=1/2.
$$
Approximations (Picard's iteration)
$$
y_0(x)=0,\quad y _1(x)=0+\int_0^x \big(s^2+y_0(s)\big)\,ds=\frac{x^3}{3}, \quad \\
y _2(x)=0+\int_0^x \big(s^2+y_1(s)\big)\,ds=\int_0^x\left(s^2+\frac{s^6}{9}\right)\,ds=\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^{7}}{63}, \\
y _3(x)=0+\!\!\int_0^x\! \big(s^2+y_2(s)\big)\,ds=\!\int_0^x\!\left(s^2+\frac{s^6}{9}+\frac{2s^{10}}{189}+\frac{s^{14}}{63^2}\right)\,ds=\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^{7}}{63}+\frac{2x^{11}}{2079}+\cdots
$$

Comment: so is the interval [-h,h] [-1/2, 1/2]?